# Can't get Apache 2.2.21 to compile with OpenSSL support

Tags: centos5, httpd, openssl, make

Alright -- having a bad couple days here compiling Apache 2.2.21 on CentOS 5.7 with the following configure commands:

```
./configure --enable-ssl=shared --with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl
```

I've compiled from source OpenSSL 1.0.0e from source:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared zlib-dynamic
```

I attempt to start Apache and it returns:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_servername`

If I look at how the libraries are linked, this is what I get:

`[root@web1 modules]# ldd mod_ssl.so 
libssl.so.6 => /lib64/libssl.so.6 (0x00002aaaaace4000)
libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00002aaaaaf30000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aaaab281000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002aaaab486000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002aaaab69a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab8b5000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00002aaaabc0e000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00002aaaabe3c000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00002aaaac0d1000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00002aaaac2d4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00002aaaac4f9000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00002aaaac702000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002aaaac904000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00002aaaacb19000)
libsepol.so.1 => /lib64/libsepol.so.1 (0x00002aaaacd32000)`

Basically, I've tired compiling from source OpenSSL (both 0.9.8r and 1e), having yum reinstall from the repos, done a `make clean` and remade both OpenSSL and Apache numerous times -- but I can't get it to compile into the apache base or dynamically as a shared object file.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update 1:**

After doing a `make clean` and `make distclean`, I've reconfigured with the same parameters as above without any effect.

The config.log is at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GeZhTc8n).

**Update 2:**

Modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH had no effect on the lib-deps of mod_ssl.so.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've compiled and recompiled many times, and verified with `ldconfig` that the OpenSSL libs dir is in my path, and included in ld.so.conf.  Still cannot get httpd/mod_ssl to load the library at runtime.

Comment: Is this still an open question you are interested in? If so, I can provide detailes steps since I did this recently on my CentOS 6.3. I was enabling FIPS on OpenSSL and Apache.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I'm interested - please do post an answer!

Answer (score 4):

When you compiled Apache you should have "--enable-so". I think you must have because the so module is trying to load.

Also after compiling openssl ensure the system can find the shared library with
"/sbin/ldconfig -v /usr/local/openssl/lib"

and I also like to edit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf to add a line for /usr/local/openssl/lib

Comment: That's correct.  I've tried with `--enable-so` and without (and then compiling it into httpd).  Either way do it, it will not load the libssl.so.* files no matter where they are when they're in the library path, and everything in between, trying builds of apache from 2.2.19-2.2.21 and openssl.0.9.8.r-1.0.0e.

Comment: Fresh install of ScientificLinux 5.5 without openssl-devel.<br>openssl 1.0.0e<br>./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/openssl100e linux-elf shared; make install<br>cd /usr/local; ln -s openssl100e ssl<br>/sbin/ldconfig -v /usr/local/ssl/lib<br><br>Apache 2.2.21:<br>--prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl and others.<br>bin/apachectl -M | grep ssl says "ssl_module (shared)"<br>Copied a generic server.crt and server.key into the conf directory, uncommented conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf<br>/usr/local/servers/bin/apachectl start worked and nmap shows 80 and 443 open.

Comment: Had the same problem it was resolved when doing the "/sbin/ldconfig -v /usr/local/openssl/lib" command. Although i had to use "sudo" and i had not compiled it in "/usr/local/openssl".

Answer (score 2):

I recall that openssl doesn't make shared libraries by default.
I do this:

./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/openssl linux-elf shared

Then you still have to do ldconfig as above. And tell apache where to find ssl libs.

Comment: Correct, and OpenSSL has been compiled this way.  Apache will not link the library to the libraries installed from compiling OpenSSL nor through yum and the CentOS repos.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem few minutes again, so I add:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

and the parameter for ./configure (Apache) modified from:

```
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

to

```
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

and no its ok.

Answer (score 0):

> ldd mod_ssl.so libssl.so.6 => /lib64/libssl.so.

would indicate that you're not linking against the openssl in /usr/local. do a "make clean && makedistclean" for both your apache/openssl builds, then rebuild/install openssl. ./configure [your options] apache, and check its config.log to make sure that it's linking against the correct openssl lib.

alternatively, please provide the output of your existing config.log

Comment: No change with `make clean` and `make distclean`, but I have tried them before.  config.log link is above.

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then recheck ldd.

Comment: basically, it looks like Apache's finding the right libraries at compile-time, but not at run-time. adjusting LD_LIBRARY_PATH will give your openssl libs precedence in the search path.

Comment: After modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH var, the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely linking to the wrong OpenSSL install as pointed out previously. You should have /usr/local/ssl/lib in ld.so.conf, but try it with the following Apache configure command:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib \
./configure \
--enable-ssl \
--enable-mods-shared=all \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

Also, are you sure OpenSSL itself is compiling as intended? Could it be failing to make shared libraries itself and falling back to static but still compiling successfully?

Comment: It is compiling the `mod_ssl.so` file in `modules/`.  I'm still executing `./configure --with-ssl=the/right/dir`, and configure sees this at configure-time.  Once it compiles, and we come to runtime, it doesn't link properly to the library dictated at compile time.

Comment: You could try removing openssl-devel from your system and then try again. If you are compiling your own version of SSL, you likely don't need that. As a last resort, you can manually tell mod_ssl.so which library to use with this: http://nixos.org/patchelf.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the SELinux logs. You have to tag the binaries with the proper SELinux attribute.

Comment: SELinux is disabled.